# Textarea limit enter pressed & trim the white space from new line

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Sorry im new to JavaScript, currently im facing the issue when user copy an article that contain a lot of new line space. How can I trim it and make it only 1 new line? And how to limit the user to press <kbd>enter</kbd> key (newline)?

Example when copy some text from other source and paste to textarea it will show up like this:

```
This is 
                    //new line 
                   //new line  
                   //new line 
                  //new line 
                  //new line     
Orange
                  //new line 
                  //new line   
                  //new line  
Not apple
```

how to make it like , after copy to textarea / enter from textarea

```
This is 

orange

not apple
```

FIDDLE DEMO =
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dofqLoyu/1/)

```
my fiddle output :
------------------ 
This is 
Orange
not apple

Expected output : 
-----------------
This is 

Orange

not apple
```

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You just replace the newlines with one single newline, like this `string.replace(/\n\s*\n/g, '\n');`

Comment: Hi @adeneo, so sorry could you show it in my fiddle ?

Comment: Sure -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ddp09zvm/4/**

Comment: Hi @adeneo, thanks. Unfortunately jquery is not applicable for my current system.

Comment: jQuery wasn't really the important part of that fiddle, the string.replace was, I just used jQuery for fast DOM access.

Comment: hi @adeneo, thanks, i tried applied your method string.replace to my fiddle, but how can i add 1 newline with whitespace? instead of trim out all the newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can prevent users from inserting line breaks by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key by adding a listener. Something like this:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
textarea.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { // keyCode 13 corresponds to the Enter key
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents inserting linebreak
    }
});
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yosc5tjr/)

As for replacing multiple new lines in the string, as pointed out by @adeneo in the comments, you can use JavaScript's `string.replace()` function. You can add another listener on the `textarea` that listens on the `paste` event, like this:

```
textarea.addEventListener("paste", handler);
```

where `handler` is a function you can define that will clean the line breaks. Here's a Fiddle showing this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dofqLoyu/3/)

Comment: Hi @southrop, thanks for explanation, can I limit the users to press the Enter key up to only two times? i've tried the odeneo method, but it trim out all the newline. Can you check again my fiddle demo? i've updated. Thank you so much

Comment: If you want to have an empty line between your text, you will want to have *two* new lines rather than just one. So try using `\n\n` instead of just `\n`

Comment: I added [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dofqLoyu/3/) new fiddle showing `string.replace()` working and producing the output that you want. As for limiting the number of times a user can press Enter, you can try creating a counter of some sort. I'm not sure exactly what your use case for this is so I can't give a solid answer.

Comment: Thousand of thanks to you @southrop, for your solution and explanation. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting two \n for your text. check my answer, i show it with jquery and without jquery. 
As per i understand , You can achieve you requirement by blur function.

```js
$("#withjquery").blur(function(){ 
 $("#withjquery").val(($("#withjquery").val().replace(/\n\s*\n/g, '\n\n')));
});

function doFormat()
{
  document.getElementById("withoutjquery").value = document.getElementById("withoutjquery").value.replace(/\n\s*\n/g, '\n\n');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="withjquery" name="withjquery" rows="5" cols="40"  ></textarea>

<textarea id="withoutjquery" name="withoutjquery" rows="5" cols="40" onblur="doFormat()" ></textarea>
```